# Served licenses on multiple workstations

Tags: powerbuilder

At my work we're running Powerbuilder 12.5 and we have quite recently changed from having Local Stand-alone licenses to Served Stand-alone licenses. The main reason for doing this is so that we could run Powerbuilder through a Citrix environment.

The issue we are experiencing from doing this is that our licensing server runs out of licenses. We have a total of 9 licenses in our team and we also have 9 users.

This issue arised after we changed to the Citrix-environment. Our guess is that since our Citrix-environment is setup on multiple servers, a user will occupy one license per server it connects to. E.g. if we have two servers, 1 and 2, for the Citrix environment and 2 users, A and B, A will occupy one license on server 1 and one on server 2. B will do the same, so two users are occupying 4 license. This guess is based on the logs on the SySAM server which I do not currently have access to(yet).

What I think that I have understood from doing some google'ing is that this should work, because the SySAM licensing server should check in and out licenses using the username of a user.

I understand that there are no floating licenses for Powerbuilder, we just want to be able to spread our 9 licenses on our 9 users but the users will not always be working in the same workstation, so, to make a question out of all this: Is it possible to run Powerbuilder with a SySAM licensing server AND running Powerbuilder from different workstations(i.e. Citrix environment setup on multiple servers) for the same user?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running one SySAM process or two?

-Paul Horan-
SAP

Comment: We are running one SySAM process at a separate server

Answer (score 1):

If you take Citrix out of the question, what you're asking sounds entirely possible. Citrix, IME, always presents challenges with PowerBuilder IDE and SySAM.

Last I heard, Sybase (now SAP) supported SySAM issues without cost. You might want to call Tech Support and see if they'll take you through the issue.

Good luck,

Terry.